# Rails: Cannot save the JSON request as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, url-routing

I want to simply save the `token` parameter I receive from the JSON request, but I simply cannot get to show if it is actually saved. I've observed that if you do a POST request with JSON parameters rails routes it to the `create` method. And I set my global variables attribute (in this case **token**), however when it redirects to the **index.html.erb** it gives me the error below

```
<h1>
  NoMethodError in
  Inits#show
</h1>

<p>
  Showing <i>/Users/alioral/Desktop/Rails/testApp2/app/views/inits/show.html.erb</i> where line <b>#3</b> raised:
  <pre><code>undefined method `token' for nil:NilClass</code></pre>
</p>
```

Here is my controller class;

```
class InitsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def show
  end
  def create
      @init=Init.new("token"=>params[:token])
      @init.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @init }
        format.json { render json: @init }
      end
  end
end
```

And just in case here is the model I've generated (without using scaffold);

```
class Init < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :token
end
```

Here is my **show.html.erb** file;

```
<h1>Hello, World</h1>
<b>The token is:</b>
<%= @init.token%>
```

Comment: Please, show your `app/views/inits/show.html.erb` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create does not redirect to index, it redirects to the new created @init path. Second, it looks like the show haml file contains a reference (in line 3) to @init.token, and since @init is nil you get this error.

Comment: Thank you so much for response. Would please explain how could the @init is nil. I'm sure that it receives the JSON requests parameter. Could it be because the params[:token] is nil?

Comment: No, @init variable in `show` action **is not** the same than in `create` action. You should initialize it with `@init = Init.find(params[:id])` in show action.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but this is like a pre-login function where I do not have it's id but rather have it's id's corresponding value. Assume that there is table like [id][value]. I will be receiving the value via the JSON request and later on will obtain the id information

Comment: try to replace
`format.html { redirect_to @init }`
with
`format.html { render :show }`

Comment: Works like a charm thank you so much!. And what if I would like to provide the json version. Would I have to create any changes in there as well?

Comment: I would not recommend `render :show` as it's not aware of page refreshes. If the user hits CMD/CTRL-R a new object will be created. That's one of the reason why there is typically redirect after a POST action

Answer (score 0):

The instance variables (the ones that starts with @) doesn't survive redirect. For every request a new instance of controller is made with the `@init` variable unset.

When you call `render ...` it's still with the original @init, but when you call redirect, then client issue a new HTTP request and on the server side there is new controller instantiated and your `@init` in the `#show` action is nil then.

**update**: So in your controller you should have something like this in your show method:

```
def show
  @init = Init.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: So you would advise me to use the render method in order to direct the variable `@init` without losing it's information?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the redirect - the standard way is that the ID of the object is passed in the URL. You only need to fetch object from that ID - like in the updated answer above.